# Gibt es einen klaren Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen "bedauern" und "bereuen"?

Tags: meaning

Man hat den Spruch ja schon mal gehört:

> Lieber bereuen, etwas getan zu haben, als bedauern, es nicht getan zu haben.

Eben kam mir der Spruch ohne die zusätzliche Qualifikation der Verben unter, mit der Bitte zuzustimmen oder zu widersprechen:

> Lieber etwas bereuen, als etwas bedauern.

Ohne diese zusätzliche Qualifikation der Verben scheinen mir *bedauern* oder *bereuen* vollkommen austauschbar.

Könnte man denn nicht genauso gut

> Lieber bedauern, etwas getan zu haben, als bereuen, es nicht getan zu haben.

schreiben? Warum (nicht)?

Comment: Man kann bedauern, daß man sterblich ist, aber man kann es nicht bereuen. Das geht nur mit selbstverschuldeten Dingen.

Comment: Außerdem kann man etwas bedauern, ohne es zu bereuen - z..B. eine Aktion, die man zwar traurig, aber trotzdem richtig findet (Typischer Fall von "Sachzwang", gerne angewendet im Umfeld von "Kollateralschaden").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Etwas bereuen ist viel stärker als etwas nur zu bedauern. Wenn ich bedauere, etwas nicht getan zu haben, könnte ich sagen "ich hätte ja doch gerne noch xyz gemacht". Wenn ich bereue, etwas getan zu haben, würde ich eher sagen "hätte ich doch nur nicht xyz gemacht".

> Ich bereue es, mich betrunken ans Steuer gesetzt zu haben.

ist ok, aber

> Ich bedaure es, mich betrunken ans Steuer gesetzt zu haben.

klingt seltsam.

Ohne Kontext ist Dein Beispielspruch schwer einzuordnen. Ich würde "bereuen" mit den potentiell schlimmeren Konsequenzen verwenden: Generell würde ich lieber nur etwas bedauern als etwas bereuen.

Man kann übrigens auch etwas bedauern, was man nicht selbst getan oder verschuldet hat.

> Bedaure, die Krapfen sind ausverkauft.
>
> Ich bedauere ja immer noch, dass dich der Lehrer damals nicht beim Abschreiben erwischt hat.

Answer (score 5):

Bereuen dürfte wohl von  Reue kommen. Hier wird für eine Sache, die man vollendet hat und als falsch anerkannt hat, die Reue geleistet.
Im Fall des Bedauerns wurde diese Sache - möglicherweise als gut betrachtet - noch nicht ausgeführt. So wäre die Reue hier noch gar nicht möglich.

Comment: Ich glaub Du bist auf dem richtigen Pfad. Wenn man etwas bereut, dann bedeutet das in der Regel, dass man Reue zeigt, d.h. das naechste mal anders handeln wuerde. Beim Bedauern ist das nicht unbedingt der Fall. So kann z.B. ein Zahnarzt durchauch bedauern dass er dem Patienten eine schmerzhafte Behandlung verabreichen muss, bereuen wuerde er es aber nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube in dem Beispiel sind die beiden Verben in der Tat mehr oder weniger austauschbar. ich finde aber wohl, dass die beiden Worte verschiedene Bedeutungen haben (können):

Bereuen: Reue wegen einer vergangene Tat oder Handlung verspüren. Stärker als bedauern. Man kann bereuen eher nicht für Handlungen anderer oder für unverschuldete Sachverhalte benutzen.

Geht:

> Ich bereue, mich nicht von ihr verabschiedet zu haben.

Geht nicht:

> Ich bereue, dass ihr dieses Unglück zugestoßen ist.

Geht nicht:

> Ich bereue es, dass er sie gestern erschossen hat.

(Wobei die beiden letzten gehen könnten, wenn der Sprecher glaubt, er hätte es verhindern können)

Bedauern: bedauern hingegen drückt die sympatische Anteilnahme an einem unglücklichen oder unangenehmen Zustand oder Ereignis aus.

Geht, aber eher schwach:

> Ich bedauere, mich nicht von ihr verabschiedet zu haben.

Geht:

> Ich bedauere, dass ihr dieses Unglück zugestoßen ist.

Geht:

> Ich bedauere, dass er sie gestern erschossen hat.

(letzteres klingt aber sehr komisch, es klingt für mich fast, als sollte da ein "aber" folgen, weil es doch sehr distanziert und förmlich klingt).

Die beiden Verben haben einen gemeinsamen Anwendungsbereich, nämlich eigene, in der Vergangenheit liegende Handlungen, in dem sie austauschbar sind, aber ich finde jedes der beiden hat ausserdem seinen eigenen Kontext, in dem dies nicht der Fall ist.

Allerdings handelt es sich bei all dem hier nur um mein Sprachgefühl. Der Duden gibt z.B. für bereuen als synonym "bedauern" an.